NetSuite N/Search Module search.Type.ACCOUNT with 'anyof' operator
Please could anybody help as I am getting unexpected error for the following when I am using 'anyof' operator within the filter
var accountArray = [];
var accountSearch = search.create( {
     type: search.Type.ACCOUNT,
     filters: [
          [ 'isinactive', 'is', 'F' ], 'AND',
          [ 'number', 'anyof', [ '40099', '21081', '12001' ] ]
     ],
     columns: [ 'number', 'internalid' ]
} );

accountSearch.run().each( ( result ) => {
     accountArray.push( {
          number: result.getValue( 'number' ),
          internalid: result.getValue( 'internalid' )
      );
     return true;
} );


I tried using both array and string but it works only for a single account using 'is' operator but keep getting unexpected error for 'anyof' operator

You can only use any and an array argument for list/record and some built-in  enumerable fields (e.g., transaction status)
var accountSearch = search.create( {
     type: search.Type.ACCOUNT,
     filters: [
          [ 'isinactive', 'is', 'F' ], 'AND',
          [ 
               ['number', 'is', '40099'], 'OR', 
               ['number', 'is', '21081'], 'OR', 
               ['number', 'is', '12001' ]
          ]
     ],
     columns: [ 'number', 'internalid' ]
} );

An aside: as a general rule, you don't need to include internalid as a column. The result has an id field that returns this value.So
{
  number: result.getValue( 'number' ),
  internalid: result.id
}

